# Combining arrays of angular modules?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to take two arrays of ngx modules and export them as a single array. Something like the following:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  exports: [
    CommonModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule
  ].concat([
    MatButtonModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatSidenavModule
  ])
})
export class CoreModule {}
```

Why isn't this working? I thought that, under the hood, `.concat` was just combining pointers to addresses into a new array, but the typescript complaints I'm getting seem to suggest that it matters what sort of things the arrays are pointing to in order for `.concat` to work.

Note: in addition to typescript errors, I'm also getting run-time errors  like "'mat-sidenav-container' is not a known element".

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Answer (score 2):

You should write this as,

```
const others: any[] = [
    MatButtonModule,
    MatMenuModule
];
```

and then use **`...`**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  exports: [
    CommonModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule
  ].concat(...others)
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Let me explain the problem with a simple example:

```
[1, 2].concat([3, "4"])
```

You will get an error saying

> Argument of type `(string|number)[]` is not assignable to parameter of type `number | ConcatArray<number>`

So, what this means is basically, `concat` expects the parameter to be an array of number only, since you introduce an array, `[1, 2]`, that TypeScript interprets as an array of number in the first place.

This, however, would work, since the base array is now of type `number|string` and thus `concat` accepts parameter of type `number|string`.

```
[1, "2"].concat([3, "4"])
```

I hope that explains your problem clearly. So to solve your problem, you can try something like this:

```js
exports: new Array<any>().concat([
    CommonModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule
  ]).concat([
    MatButtonModule,
    MatMenuModule
  ])
```

In this case, the base array is `new Array<any>()` and accepts `any` type parameters.

Alternatively you could also do something like this:

```js
exports: ([
    CommonModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule
  ] as any[]).concat([
    MatButtonModule,
    MatMenuModule
  ])
```

Last but not least: TypeScript is all about a **safety mechanism**, a kind of **driving assistant**. Sometimes it can be unnecessarily annoying, but you can just fool the system, depending on what you want to achieve. For example the following syntax is normally invalid `[1, 2, 3] * 4`, but still you can get around it by paraphrasing it like this `([1, 2, 3] as any) * 4`; however the result will be `NaN` and have practically no use.